# Support for HTTP "MERGE" verb in Play! Framework 2.1?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm attempting to implement an oData service on the Play! Framework.

When updating records, The oData client "JayData" uses the 'Merge' HTTP Verb/method to submit changes, however this doesn't appear to be supported at all by the Play framework.

Is there anyway to add support for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MERGE` won't be supported because it is not a [valid HTTP method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

In order to use an arbitrary HTTP method in your request, use the `execute` method from `WSRequestHolder`.

Comment: `MERGE` is not a HTTP method but a specified header on `PUT` as far as I understood it. If that is the case, you can use the `PUT` method and check for the header. I found some information about it here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541276.aspx

Comment: "The remainder of this section defines a custom HTTP MERGE method that is used in OData protocol versions prior to OData 3.0"

Comment: That's what I get for assuming an "Open" protocol by Microsoft would actually be standards compliant and easy to support!

Comment: Hi! You can configure JayData to send POST/PUT instead of MERGE/PATCH but of course your server won't be oData conformant then and you can only use it with JayData. I recommend using WebAPI provider instead which is - despite its name - is a REST provider so any REST server should be able to serve it. With that solution you loose other goodies, because oData specifies certain things that you will have to implement yourself with REST such as filtering, paging, sorting, length, projection. Anyway. we can help you with that, just ask here or on our own forum.

Comment: or you can use our nodejs+mongodb odata server